# Why isn't the playing time for women players in sports like soccer shortened in a similar way in which the playing time for women's tennis is?

Tags: rules, football

If women playing for shorter periods of time makes for better marketability in tennis, why isn’t the same logic applied to other (even more) physically grueling sports like soccer where players play for even longer periods of time? Wouldn't the women's game also benefit from some form of modification in the rules or format just as women's tennis benefitted from it?

Answer (score 3):

Because your premise is wrong.

Women playing shorter matches in tennis isn't for "marketability", it's an excuse that's been used for many years to pay less money to women. Women are just as capable of playing a high-quality 5 set match as men are, suggesting that other sports should be crippled because of an outdated notion that women aren't "strong enough" to play for as long as men is frankly a backwards, sexist suggestion.